# Joomla 3 using Wright - How to find CSS?

Tags: php, css, joomla, joomla3.0

I've got a Joomla 3 website using the Wright framework. When I try inspecting the element from the frontend, it says the CSS is coming from http://example.com/templates/template/wright/css/template.css.php

But when I go there, there's no CSS. And everything is coming from the template.css.php when I inspect from the frontend.

What or where should I look?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the file `template.css.php` exist? If so, what is in it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [Template Structure (Getting Started With Wright)](http://wright.joomlashack.com/using-wright/5-template-structure)

> The css folder has several files that start with a #*file.css. Any CSS files prefixed with a #* are automatically loaded by Wright, in numerical order.

So the files you are looking for, should be in the CSS folder.

Comment: Hi, I looked through it and there was no # or numbers next to the css files. But i did find a solution. By adding another css file called custom.css. Here you can add all your custom css, so it will avoid any overwrites if the template is updated in the future.